# fastapi 0.73.0 issue : TypeError: '<' not supported

Tags: fastapi

My code is working fine for fastapi==0.72.0.
But for fastapi==0.73.0, its throws the below error.

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Rest, there is no change in the code for the 2 versions.

It breaking at call_next response(its endpoint_function in my case)

```py
#middleware added
@project.middleware("http")
async def request_check(request:Request,endpoint_function):
   token=request.headers.get("token")
   request_url=request["path"]
   url_4th=str(request.url).split("/")[3]
   #public endpoint check
   if url_4th=="public" or url_4th=="":
      response=await endpoint_function(request)
      return response
```

Comment: Without the code, you should at least provide the full traceback which indicates where the problem is.

Comment: added. The error is simply in returning endpoint_function(call_next as per fastapi doc).

When i am switching to fastapi 0.72.0, its worked perfectly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That code would not produce that error.  You need to include the entire traceback.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been some incompatibility with fastapi and starlette -
They have since fixed it and all is working again.

Try running

```
pip3 install fastapi -U
```

This should also update starlette for you as well.